# How to implement Generic Column Name in c#.net

Tags: c#

I have 3 excel sheets, all 3 has same kind of data but the column names differs in each excel sheet. How can i design my class to handle all 3 excel sheets? in c#.net.

Comment: string column name ?

Comment: The column type can be anything. But Column Name is different. For example in 1st Excel Loan_Number, in 2nd Excel LoanNumber, in 3rd Excel Lon_Num. But all are referring to LoanNumber in database. To Upload that data to Database how to design the class?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use excelpackage (available in nuget) to read all sheets. (See: 
https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reading%20data%20from%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet&referringTitle=Home)

You can then import rows sheet by sheet

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here my problem is not reading Excel sheet, how can i have common column name. The source can be Excel or some table or anything else.